# Can't change back bar button text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationitem

By default the back button uses as a text on it a title of a viewcontroller. Can I change text on the back button without changing a title of a view controller? I need this because I have a view controller which title is too long to display and in this case I would like to display just "Back" as a caption for back button.

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is in your target..

Comment: target set should be self instead of nil

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
    UIButton *aCustomBackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; 
    [aCustomBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aCustomBackButton setTitle:@"customBack" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *aLeftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aCustomBackButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aLeftBarButtonItem;
```

For iOS 7 use below piece of code:

```
UIButton *aCustomBackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
[aCustomBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aCustomBackButton setTitle:@"customBack" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *backArrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backArrow"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backArrow];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(kScreenOrigin, topMargin, backArrow.size.width, backArrow.size.height)];
[aCustomBackButton addSubview:imageView];

UIBarButtonItem *aNegativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
aNegativeSpacer.width = -8.0;
UIBarButtonItem *aLeftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aCustomBackButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[aNegativeSpacer, aLeftBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: @user2885928 what issue with above code and please do not use sort form of the word this is not a chat room please use proper spelling for it. whatis ptr.?

Comment: " < " this is missing

Comment: I guess you are are using iOS 7. Please see my updated response.

Comment: i think there is no need to setting custome button for it @Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

Try with This code

```
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NewTitle"
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                        target:[self navigationController]
                                                        action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)
```